# why doesn`t work time sleep with the GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface

it works with `print("something")`, but not with the GUI

```
def threads():
    global text_00, text_10, bttn_00, bttn_80, bttn_81, bttn_texte

    if bttn_80["text"] == bttn_81["text"]:
        text_00.set(random.choice(bttn_texte))
        time.sleep(1)
        text_10.set(bttn_00["text"])
        time.sleep(1)
        text_80.set(bttn_00["text"])
```

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.